# Are device specific "what is your experience" questions on-topic on Android.SE?

Tags: support, question-appropriateness

I'm considering buying a Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9, with the main use as a portable "table phone". It has GSM phone functionality built-in, but  not enabled out of the box. I'm very distrustful of devices where you need to activate such a key functionality using third party software - it makes me suspect it is not going to work 100% reliably.

Is asking about whether GSM telephony is feasible on the 8.9 tab, and what peoples' *real-world* experiences are with it, on-topic on  Android.SE? It's *kinda* related to Android, but  I thought I'd check first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking about feasibility and how-to is fine.  Asking for experiences is polling, though, which falls under Not Constructive.  We generally close such questions.  Slipping it in as "How well does it work as a phone?" should be OK, though.