# Is it on topic to ask for help choosing a suitable Android device?

Tags: discussion

Let's say I'm planning to buy a new Android device. I have a certain list of criteria for the device. I want to know which devices fit most or all of my criteria, and possibly get feedback from users who have already tried the devices in question.

Would this be on or off topic here?

If it's off topic, where would it be on topic to ask that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a beta site for [hardware recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). It's for a specific type of recommendation, though, so be sure to check [their on-topic guidance](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and be sure to ask [something that counts as "high-quality" on that site](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality/206#206):

> A question on Hardware Recommendations has one of two goals:
>
> - A request for a product recommendation, OR
> - A request for information that will lead to a product decision

Comment: I did [ask it there](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2653/2416) and it was fine.

Answer (score 6):

If you check the [On topic](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page you will see that:

> Please note the following topics are expressly **off-topic** here:
>
> Questions asking the community to find or recommend something for you (a device, app, ROM, website, etc), including what to buy and where to buy it

so no, it would not be on-topic here.

As for where to ask, we have a post [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions) which may help. If you do not find what you're after there, feel free to add an answer there if you find a suitable site.

Answer (score 5):

- Quoting from reasons for closure under *off-topic* (emphasis supplied)

> Questions asking us to find or recommend an app, **device**, ROM, accessory or off-site resource are off-topic for Android Enthusiasts as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam and become obsolete quickly

- Asking for feedback on a particular device is [*polling*](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/662/131553) , which is also not permitted

AFAIK none of SE sites entertain shopping recommendations

Comment: [GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/) is a good place to compare and gather reviews, but I don't think you can *ask*

Comment: @Fiksdal [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/1465)